# Rotate minus CSS3

Tags: html, css, animation, rotation

How can i correctly rotate sign ' - ' ?
For example when i set sign + to rotating, it's all okay, they staying on place, and just rotating. There is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/t6S2F/4/)

But if i change `content: '+';` to `content: '-';` i get rotating minus by axis, but not stayed on place. There is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/t6S2F/3/).

Is it real to set minus, rotate like plus ?

Comment: The `-` is not vertically centered, we don't have any reliable solution to center it, I've tried adding a `padding-bottom:.2em` to make it centered (maybe not really) http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/t6S2F/8/ However it's not reliable and stable, different browsers may render it differently. You should render the `-` sign yourself (without using the `-` character).

Answer (score 2):

Use the MINUS SIGN U+2212 “−”, which is specifically a mathematical operator, instead of the common Ascii hyphen, formally known as HYPHEN-MINUS U+002D “-”, which is semantically ambiguous and typographically inferior (it has to work, in some minimal sense, as a punctuation hyphen, as an en dash, as a minus sign, and in a few other roles too, so it cannot do any particular role well). In particular, MINUS SIGN is (in any decently designed font) of the same width as PLUS SIGN and appears in the same vertical position as the horizontal stroke of PLUS SIGN. In a word, its design matches that of “+”.

In CSS, you can write

```
 content: '\2212';
```

Alternatively, you can use MINUS SIGN itself:

```
 content: '−';
```

But then you need to be careful with character encoding.

Comment: Great Answer. I love SO as I can learn something new every hour

Answer (score 1):

If sign **-** stands alone , you can do : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t6S2F/11/)**

```
line-height:0;/* reduce height to none; */
padding-bottom:0.2em;/* tune gap under font */
```

If it is among  or aside other content , add `vertical-align:middle;/* or what suits you best */`

---

`inline-block` seems more accurate here , i believe.

Answer (score 0):

You could position your :before pseudo elements centrally using absolute then set widths and heights. Doing this the transforms will apply to the center by default.

http://jsfiddle.net/sYm3T/

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: gray;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.box:before {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height:31px;
    position:absolute;
    content: '-';
    margin-left:-20px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s all;
}

.box.plus:before {
    content: '+';
}
.box.minus:before {
    content: '-';
}

.box:hover::before
{
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Another solution would be to look into the transform-origin property to adjust where the 'center' of the transform occurs.